# What's wrong with my FB connect implementation?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, facebook

I'm working on a site that uses Facebook connect for single signon. It seems to work OK in all browsers except IE. When clicking the "connect" button in IE I get the login popup appear but instead of showing the login dialog it tries to display

http://dev.mysite.com/?fb_xd_fragment#?=&cb=f2f370e9419aa2c&relation=opener&transport=fragment&frame=f366b7f0bcf79f4&result=%7B%22perms%22%3A%22email%2Cpublish_stream%22%2C%22selected_profiles%22%3A674561930%2C%22session%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22session_key%5C%22%3A%5C%222.MRrJZlv1JeAhFW5koMUK_g__.3600.1292436000-674561930%5C%22%2C%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%22674561930%5C%22%2C%5C%22expires%5C%22%3A1292436000%2C%5C%22secret%5C%22%3A%5C%22ex6QAIvguKufbSs5s_3TNw__%5C%22%2C%5C%22base_domain%5C%22%3A%5C%22stageidol.se%5C%22%2C%5C%22access_token%5C%22%3A%5C%22122307124493264%7C2.MRrJZlv1JeAhFW5koMUK_g__.3600.1292436000-674561930%7CP4DnM9QFx44akf0HjfftI40G7No%5C%22%2C%5C%22sig%5C%22%3A%5C%223d7125091d2a633ccf3dbead153b185c%5C%22%7D%22%7D

Which can't load and is just white. IE also displays an errormessage about all.js (included by FB connect):

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0;
>   .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Wed, 15
>   Dec 2010 16:11:50 UTC
>
> Message: Permission denied Line: 16
>   Char: 2188 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Obviously hard to debug since it's minified JS.

Comment: In the [Facebook JavaScript SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) they do mention [http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js) for use debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the channelURl, that should solve your problem.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.init/

```
<script>
   FB.init({
     appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
    channelUrl  : 'http://example.com/channel.html'  // custom channel
   });
 </script>
```

Content of channel.html :

```
<script>
document.domain = "example.com";
</script>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: The page the login is initialized from must also have the correct `document.domain` value as well as `channel.html`